# Exporting graph object for later use

Tags: bugs, graphs-and-networks, export, import

**Bug introduced in 10.0 or earlier and fixed in 12.0**

---

We are planning to analyze the geometry of artery branch patterns. We convert the binarized image into graph object using `MorphologicalGraph[]`. To avoid the complexity of the code for later analysis, we want to save the graph objects to a separate file. We tried

```
Export["graphList.m", obtainBranchGraphList]
```

and tried to use the object later. When we import the data using

```
g2 = Import["graphList.m"]
```

resulting `g2` seem to contain all the information of the graph. However, the content of `g2` is something like

```
Graph[{3, 5, 4, 13, 17, 26, 21, 42}, {3 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
  4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 17 \[UndirectedEdge] 26, 
  21 \[UndirectedEdge] 26, 21 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
  42 \[UndirectedEdge] 26, 
    21 \[UndirectedEdge] 
     13}, {VertexLabels -> {"Name", 8 -> None, 12 -> None, 22 -> None, 
      14 -> None, 2 -> None, 29 -> None, 41 -> None, 38 -> None, 
      37 -> None, 20 -> None, 32 -> None, 18 -> None, 25 -> None, 
      7 -> None, 9 -> None, 19 -> None, 30 -> None, 16 -> None, 
      23 -> None, 39 -> None, 34 -> None, 40 -> None, 11 -> None, 
      44 -> None, 6 -> None, 36 -> None, 33 -> None, 1 -> None, 
      15 -> None, 35 -> None, 28 -> None, 24 -> None, 10 -> None, 
      27 -> None, 43 -> None, 31 -> None}, 
    VertexCoordinates -> {{2096.5, 1813.5}, {2093.5, 1795.5}, {2144.5, 
       1810.5}, {2243.5, 1600.5}, {1892.5, 1581.5}, {1926.5, 
       1559.5}, {1942.5, 1571.5}, {1713.5, 1298.5}}}]
```

and we could not reconstruct the graph from `g2`. Is there any way to convert this text to graph object?

Thank you very much in advance.

Takashi.

Comment: if you comment out `VertexLabels -> ..., `  part or change it to `VertexLabels -> "Name"`  it works fine.

Comment: see also [DumpSave](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DumpSave.html) and [Get](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Get.html), e.g. `DumpSave["graphList.mx", obtainBranchGraphList]` and `Get["graphList.mx"]`

Comment: @kglr DumpSave will only hide the internal corruption temporarily. The bug is still there and will no doubt surface in a nastier way later.

Comment: @Szabolcs, right; I didn't mean to suggest DumpSave/Get as a fix; just as an alternative to Export/Import.

Answer (score 13):

This is, sadly, due to some long-standing bugs in Mathematica that I have reported multiple times, but Wolfram fails to take seriously.  I don't understand how they can seriously keep marketing Mathematica for graph/network analysis for as long as even basic things don't work.

Here's what happens, in short:

There are several operations (such as `VertexDelete`, `EdgeDelete`, etc.) which will corrupt the internal structure of the graph whenever properties are present.  Properties can be something as harmless looking as vertex labels.

`Graph` is an atomic object, and it is *not* represented internally through its `InputForm`. However, when you export it (as well as in several other situations) it does need to be converted to input form.  When you re-import it, Mathematica notices that the structure is corrupted and refuses to construct the graph.

I do not know which specific bug (or which function) corrupted *your* graph. It is likely one of the ones I mentioned (edge/vertex deletions or additions).

However, I can see that vertex labels are assigned to non-existent vertices, such as vertex `8`.  You probably `VertexDelete`d these, which may have also triggered adding the `v -> None` rules to the vertex labels (yet another long-standing bug).

You can recover your graph by deleting the `VertexLabels -> ...` bit, e.g. using

```
DeleteCases[yourImportedGraph, VertexLabels -> _, Infinity]
```

But once again: this is not your fault, it's due to a set of bugs affecting even the most fundamental operations one would want to do with graphs in Mathematica.  So please do complain and report it to [Wolfram Support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! It makes sense since we used VertexDelete[] to simplify the network structure. And we succeeded in recovering the original graph using DeleteCases[].

Comment: Recently we checked whether this issue still remains, and found that Mathematica worked just as expected now.